# How to solve this congruence of triangles geometrically?

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

> Find x.
>
> [image]

---

Solution with trigonometry:

> First there are the missing angles ...
>
> Superior = $180 - 13 - 32 = 135$
>
> Bottom = $180 - 13 - 24 = 143$
>
> By the breast theorem we have to
>   $$\frac{9 \sqrt{2}}{sen(13)}=\frac{Diagonal}{sen(135)} \to Diagonal=\frac{9 \sqrt{2} \cdot sen(135)}{sen(13)}$$
>   Also in other triangle...
>   $$\frac{x}{sen(13)}=\frac{Diagonal}{sen(143)} \to x = \frac{Diagonal \cdot sen(13)}{sen(143)}$$
>   Using what we know diagonally
>   $$x = \frac{9 \sqrt{2} \cdot sen(135) \cdot sen(13)}{sen(13) \cdot sen(143)}=\frac{9 \sqrt{2} \cdot sen(135)}{sen(143)}$$

Comment: What is the question? Find x?

Comment: Is this not already a geometric solution? There's really nothing I can see since the values of the angles are somewhat arbitrary (and ugly) numbers.

Comment: I strongly doubt there is a non-trigonometric solution, since $x=9/\sin(143)$ and $\sin(143)$ is transcendental.

Comment: Sines of integer degree angles are algebraic, not transcendental.  But the sines of the angles involved here cannot be expressed without cube roots --> can't be constructed --> no solution by elementary geometry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the figure $ x = 3 $. However, the lenght that you seek is $ 5x = 15 $ [image]

In your case $$x = \frac{9 \sqrt{2} \cdot sen(135)}{sen(143)} = \frac{9 \sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}{\frac{3}{5}} = 15 $$

Comment: Nice construction, but it's only an approximation. Your claimed $3$-$4$-$5$ right triangle is only _approximately_ a $3$-$4$-$5$ right triangle.

Comment: True! You can replace $ 3x = 5x \sin 37$, and you will get the same.

Comment: Thank you Dunket.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a shorter way:

[image]

Here, you can use what you called breast theorem on $\Delta ABC$, you will find the same answer.